# Efficiency of MongoDB's db.collection.distinct() for every user vs saving as a db entry and retrieving results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, database-design, database

In my `nodeJS` app I query `mongoDB` for distinct values for a particular database field. This returns an array of roughly 3000 values.

Every user must get this data for every session (as it's integral to running the app).

I'm wondering whether it's more efficient (and faster) to do this for every single user:

```
 db.collection.distinct({"value"}, function(data){
    // save the data in a variable
 })
```

Or whether I should do a server-side loading of the distinct values (say, once a day), then save it as a db entry for every user to retrieve, like this:

```
// Server-side:

 db.collection.distinct({"value"}, function(data){
    // save the data to MongoDB as a document
 }) 

// Client-side:

 db.serverInfo.find({name: "uniqueEntries"}, function(data){
    // Save to browser as a variable
 })
```

I've tested this myself and can't notice much of a difference, but I'm the only one using the app at the moment. Once I get 10/100/1000/10,000 users I'm wondering which will be best to use here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on this field MongoDB should be able to return the result of the distinct() operation using only the index which should make it fast enough.

But, as with all performance questions, profiling is the best way to be sure, or in the case of MongoDB, use the `explain` option to see what's happening under the covers.